# Julia : How to fill a matrix column by column?

Tags: matrix, vector, julia

I have 5000 vectors; each one has a length of 10000 (values)

I want to fill a matrix column by column such that each columns represents a vector.

5000 columns and 10000 rows.

it did't work in this way . I have this structure:

```
 vector = Vector() 
for i in 1:5000 
   println(vector[i]) 
end
```

for example

```
 julia> vector[502]
```

`10000-element Array{Float64,1}: -3.0 1.0 . . . -2.0`

when I do

```
a = zeros(10000,0) 
 for v in vector 
   a = hcat(a,v) 
 end
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost identical to the question you asked previously on populating a matrix row by row.  The solution likewise is:

```
A = [rand(10000) for idx in 1:5000];
B = hcat(A...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = zeros(10000,0)
vector = #whatever is here

for v in vector
    a = hcat(a,v)
end
```

**Note**
If you get a

```
**ERROR: ArgumentError: number of rows of each array must match**
```

the loop must be

```
        a = hcat(a,v')
```

Comment: it did't work . l have this structure :   vector = Vector()  for i in 1:5000 println(vector[i]) end                                                                                                            for example                                                                                                    julia> vector[502]
10000-element Array{Float64,1}:
-3.0
1.0
.
.
.
-2.0                                                                                                            when l do a = zeros(10000,0)  vector= Vectors()   for v in vector
    a = hcat(a,v)
end